# Map-ing over ConduitM?

Tags: haskell

How can I implement the following in [Conduit](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.13/conduit-combinators-1.1.1/Conduit.html#v:decodeUtf8C)?

Given a conduit whose input is of type `a` and output is of type `b`, output a new conduit that returns a type of `c`, i.e. rather than `b`.

`g :: Monad m => ConduitM a b m () -> (b -> c) -> ConduitM a c m ()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the docs, this is just `mapOutput`, right?

https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.13/conduit-1.2.10/Data-Conduit.html#t:mapOutput